# Запоминание значения int в последующих циклах

Tags: java

Суть в чем, создал я рулетку, на старт игры, игроку дается 10000 очков,

```
int allmoney=10000;
```

Первая ставка не может превышать 10000

```
if(summa>allmoney){
```

int summa Это наша ставка.
Если ставка сыграла, значение summa умножается на 2, и прибавляется к allmoney, так было задумано... Но в конце игры, программа задает вопрос "Хотите сыграть еще раз?", после ответа "Да" игра начинается заново, и снова

```
int allmoney=10000;
```

А я хочу сделать так, что в новой игре это значение равнялось значению из предыдущей игры.

```
import java.io.UTFDataFormatException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;
    public class Bender {

static boolean playAgain = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (playAgain) {
        Game();
    }
}

public static void Game() {
    String[] colors = {"Черное", "Красное"};
    String[] parity = {"Четное", "Нечетное"};
  int allmoney=10000;
    Random random = new Random();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
    boolean isPlaying = true;
    while (isPlaying) {
        System.out.println("Сделайте вашу ставку. Вы можете поставить на Красное или Черное, на Четное или Нечетное.");
        String stavka = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Какую сумму ставите?");
        int summa = scanner.nextInt();
       if(summa>allmoney){
           System.out.println("У вас не хватает денег для этой ставки.");
      break;
       }

        int colorIndex = random.nextInt(colors.length);
        int number = random.nextInt(36);
        System.out.println("Выпало " + parity[number % 2] + " " + number + " " + colors[colorIndex]);
        if (stavka.equals(colors[colorIndex]) || stavka.equals(parity[number % 2]) || stavka.equals(number)) {
            System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили! Выигрыш составляет: " + summa * 2);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Вы проиграли");
            allmoney=allmoney-summa;
        }
        System.out.println("Делаем ставку еще раз?");
        String otvet = scanner.next();
        if (otvet.equals("Да")) {
            System.out.println("Продолжаем!");
        }
          if (otvet.equals("Нет")) {
              isPlaying = false;
             playAgain = false;
              System.out.println("Жаль. До встречи!");
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вынесите   `int allmoney=10000;` за пределы `Game()`, чтобы она не затиралась.

```
 if (stavka.equals(colors[colorIndex]) || stavka.equals(parity[number % 2]) || stavka.equals(number)) {
    System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили! Выигрыш составляет: " + summa * 2);
    // далее нужно эту сумму прибавить к общей

allmoney = allmoney + summa * 2;
        }
```

после ваша сумма сохранится при повторной игре